# Emails are going to spam while checks are good

Tags: email, spam, gmail

I used G Suite for sending emails and the problem was that my mails were in in spam because they were sent from the Google servers, **some of these IP's are on the popular blacklist** now. Google knows about this problem and they said: "We're trying to arrange with blacklist support, so you should wait and maybe in future all will be OK". Of course this variant I don't like.

I have a correct DKIM / DMARC / SPF records in my domains. **Spam score** (I used [Mail Tester](https://www.mail-tester.com) for testing) was always near **8/10**. Because the sender IP was in ~4 blacklists.

So I decided to use the Zoho Mail hosting. I set up one of my domains and go to Zoho. But the problem is the same: **my emails are going to spam** (on Gmail and others mailboxes). All checks are good, **spam score** on Mail Tester is **10/10**, sometimes sender IP was just on 1 blacklist (Mail Tester said that IP isn't on any blacklist).

Also, I opened the original message and ALL checks are 'pass'.

**What can be the problem?** **Any suggestions?**